# how to extract char type elements from a string type line and add to a list in c

Tags: c, string, list, char

I have a running c program which defines a list and displays strings stored in list. I am trying to change code to get char elements out of list to display on console window which is not working. Code is below which shows not only commented out code lines of list with string, but also modified code too to get char elements .

```
struct List
{
    char *data;
    struct List *next;
};
typedef struct List list;

int main()
{
    char line[25];
    FILE *input_file;

    list *tokens = NULL;
    list *current = NULL;

    input_file = fopen("test.evl", "r");

    if (input_file == NULL)
    {
    printf("I cant read:%d\n", errno);
    printf("I cant read:%s\n", strerror(errno));
    perror("I cant read");
    fprintf(stderr, "I cant read");
    }

    //while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), input_file) != NULL)
    //{
    //  list *node = NULL;
    //  current = malloc(sizeof(list));
    //  current->data = strdup(line);
    //  current->next = NULL;
    //  if (tokens == NULL)
    //  {
    //      tokens = current;
    //  }
    //  else
    //  {
    //      node = tokens;
    //      while (node->next != NULL)
    //          node = node->next;
    //      node->next = current;
    //  }
    //}

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), input_file)!=NULL)
    {
        list *node = NULL;
        current = malloc(sizeof(list));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(line); i++)
        {
            current->data = (line[i]);
            current->next = NULL;
            if (tokens == NULL)
            {
                tokens = current;
            }
            else
            {
                node = tokens;
                while (node->next != NULL)
                    node = node->next;
                node->next = current;
            }
         }
     }

     for (current = tokens; current; current = current->next)
    {
        //printf("%s", current->data);//for string output works
        printf("%c\n", current->data);//for char output not working
    }

    if (input_file)
    {
        fclose(input_file);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

output for while loop which gives strings I can see, but while loop which I use to implement char doesn't shows output. What can be issue in my approach. If my approach is right what can be solution to get output of this list as char type?

If input file has this line:

// a comment
module top;

Then for string case output is

// a comment
module top;

But once we change it to char case output will come out as

/
/

a

c
o
m
m
e
n
t

m
o
d
u
l
e

t
o
p
;

To make long story short I need to implement below code with a list

```
char line[25];
for (int line_no = 1;fgets(line, sizeof(line), input_file) != NULL; ++line_no)
{
    // We should break line into tokens here
    //for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(line);++i)
    {

        printf("%c\n",line[i]);//need to implement ths logic with a list
    }
    //printf("%s", line);//this works with my list
}
```

Comment: What compiler/options are you using that does not warn about `current->data = (line[i]);` and `printf("%c\n", current->data);`?

Comment: @chux I am using visual studio, but don't see any errors or warnings. although I couldn't figure out where are those compiler options in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

**Updated in response to comment**

To the best of my understanding of the problem, just a few minor tweaks are needed in order to achieve the desired output. I'm not sure whether you want the word spacing to be part of the data, or just a matter of display. I chose the latter.

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), input_file)!=NULL)
{
    int len=strlen(line); //added
    list *node = NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)//modified
    {
        current = malloc(sizeof(list));
        current->data = malloc(sizeof(char)); //added
        *(current->data)= line[i]; //added
        current->next = NULL;
        if (tokens == NULL)
        {
            tokens = current;
        }
        else
        {
            node = tokens;
            while (node->next != NULL)
                node = node->next;
            node->next = current;
        }
     }
 }

 for (current = tokens; current; current = current->next)
{
    //printf("%s", current->data);//for string output works
    printf("%c ", *(current->data)); //modified
    if(' ' == *(current->data)) putchar('\n'); // added
}
// cleanup
```

The above produces:

/ /
a
c o m m e n t
m o d u l e
t o p ;

Comment: No output with "(current->data)[0], or *(current->data)", I had tried those before I posted this question here. When I try current->data=strdup(line[i]); it shows exception "Excess violation reading location 0x0000002F". That's why I excluded strdup. Can you try it at your end I have posted all code

Comment: I left out the inner loop `for (size_t i = 0; i < ...`.  Are you not trying to read each line and store it in a list? Please give an example of input, and what you want to see as output. Show us 3 lines of example, and tell us what you want to happen to them.

Comment: I have already mentioned for strings it works which is reading whole line, inner loop addition is to read individual letters as a char on each line. I can read file as a char too, but again that is not I am looking for. For example if I have one input line in a file "I work ". Now if we read it as a string output is "I work", but if we read it as a char output is "I" " " "w" "o" "r" "k". Now what if we read as "I work" but then convert it to "I" " " "w" "o" "r" "k". Second for loop is to achieve that purpose.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. let me check.

Comment: Without lists this thing I have implemented, but list the way I have defined is not working for this other wise working case.

Comment: Let me get this clearly:  you want *each line* to be stored as an element of the list, and when displaying, you want each letter then to be displayed individually according to the example? Right now, each letter is stored as an element of the list.

Comment: I have updated my question to give you code which runs fine and now I need to implement that code with help of a list. By running that loop u can check what output I want. I am updating my code step by step to make it large. First step was to see output required without a list., now same output I want with help of a list. Oh I noticed now you have updated answer too, let me try that too

Comment: I modified code according to your answer still no output. Did you see output at your end by running code?

Comment: @ArifMahmood yes, that is the output when when I run the program using the string that you gave. I can run the program on any file and get similar output. Verify your code.

Comment: I was leaving current = malloc(sizeof(list)); outside of inner for loop that was only issue. once I saw your code carefully and placed it inside I saw output lol

Comment: @ArifMahmood That is the problem with C: attention to detail.

Comment: One more thing, how can we convert current->data = (line[i]); again to string so that we can use %s in printf instead of %c?

Comment: @Arif In which line?

Comment: line[i] is now of char type so that's why we use %c in printf, now if we change line[I] to string we can change %c to %s again. but I tried strncpy and memcpy meantime so both worked. this my defined list doesn't work if use it inside if else blocks inside inner for loop. keeps repeating same line. I have seen smarter built-in lists in c++ which iterate through lines once we add strings to those.

Comment: @ArifMahmood instead of `current->data = malloc(sizeof(char))`, use `current->data = malloc(sizeof(char)*2)`. Then: after `*(current->data)= line[i];`, add  `*current->data[1]= '\0';`. You will then be able to use `printf("%s", current->data);` instead of `printf("%c ", *(current->data));`.

Comment: I see a red line under current of *current->data[1]= '\0';.

Comment: @Arif please remove the *. It should be `current->data[1]= '\0';`.

Comment: One more question if you can answer for same code. I am changing char *data; member in struct List to An_element *data where An_element is another struct with a member char str [25]. Once I run program I see exception at line "current = malloc(sizeof(list));". I want to use a struct or class to get same results on this example

Comment: @ArifMahmood You'll get a larger audience and better responses if you start a new question. I suppose the original question has already been answered.

Comment: Actually even on this simpler problem I got responses only from you, that looks more complex and I doubt anyone else will like to respond

Comment: I will take a look. People actually help a lot. The key is to make the problem very easy for them to understand, since this is a volunteer kind of thing and people have other responsibilities.